# Executing a SQL Server stored procedure that deletes data using WebMatrix

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, webmatrix

I'm trying to delete rows in a SQL Server database using a stored procedure with WebMatrix. Nothing happens. Below is my code.

I'm positive that the variable `IDphoto` returns a value.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SD_PhotoDeleteLikes]
    @IDphoto int
AS 
    DELETE FROM photoLikes 
    WHERE [IDphoto] = @IDphoto
```

and this is how I'm calling the stored procedure from the code behind

```
public static string DeleteLike(int IDphoto)
{
    using (db) 
    { 
        db.Execute("Exec SD_PhotoDeleteLikes @0", IDphoto); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: is db defined elsewhere in the class?